# Allow a request to question owner to reconsider correct answer to their question

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, accepted-answer

Often questions have more than one correct answer, and sometimes the answer with the most votes is not selected as the right answer. Sometimes is because the most-voted answer was submitted later. Yet this responses have more comprehensive, complete and up to date answers to the original question. Thus why they are the most-voted answers.

How about, once this scenario happens, the owner of the question is notified or requested by the owner of the most-voted answer to reconsider the correct answer to the question?

Comment: Quite often the Most Voted answer is not the one that actually works for the OP, so I think this would be a bad idea. The current tooltip for the Accept check mark is "Click to set this answer as **your** accepted answer", which I think is correct and should not be changed.

Comment: How about you just drop the asker a comment if you think the accepted answer should be a different one?

Comment: How about no? Let's go with that. No.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The OP for any question is notified whenever any answer is posted to a question of theirs.  If they are sufficiently motivated they can look at an answer, even if it is posted much later than an existing answer that solved the OP's problem, and if the OP prefers it they can choose to accept the later answer.

Keep in mind that the green checkmark doesn't indicate "the best answer", it's simply "the answer that the OP felt best helped them solve their problem."  Votes are the way of saying, "This is the answer that the community feels is the best."

Comment: It's worth noting that I (and I'm pretty sure most) have seen questions whose "best answer" actually had a negative score, while a highly voted question sits beneath.